# WPF Short binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I really dont understand why i cant binding like it:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SomeObiect}"/>
```

In very often see something like it but in my programs dont work...
Why? :(

```
<UserControl x:Class="GAME___ala_Mario.View.Controls.SkillButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Converers="clr-namespace:GAME___ala_Mario.View.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Name="btn_Skill">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--Tło-->
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
         <!-- AND I USE BINDING LIKE IT: (always) -->
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=btn_Skill, Path=BackgroundImageSource}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And Code-behind:

```
public partial class SkillButton : UserControl
{
    [...]

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(SkillButton));
    public ImageSource BackgroundImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(BackgroundImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answer my question... 
but many of u give me a minus -.-

I don't know if this is in accordance with the standards but i do like it:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=btn_Skill}">     
    <Viewbox>
        <Image Source="{Binding BackgroundImageSource}"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

That binding change DataContext for all child so I dont need rewrite it in all bingings